# How do I 'cook' a grenade?

Tags: dishonored

I've seen references in more than one place to 'cook' a grenade, i.e. shorten it's fuse length.  But I haven't seen any references in game to doing so, or more importantly, how to do so.  How do you cook a grenade in game?

Comment: Cooking usually refers to letting the fuse run out a bit before actually throwing the grenade.  Usually games do this by having you hold the grenade button/key for a short period of time.  Then when you let go, it will throw the grenade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's rather easy; hold down the throw button (default <kbd>right-mouse</kbd> on PC) before throwing it.  Dishonored provides you a neat little UI indicator telling you how long you have until it blows.  Hold it as long as you need, then throw.  Do make sure to leave enough time for the grenade to get where it's going.